How to check if user is allowed to write in a chat by using pyrogram?
When sending messages in groups with pyrogram sometimes errors like 420 SLOWMODE_WAIT_X or even 400 USER_BANNED_IN_CHANNEL occur.
Is there a way to check if the target allows sending a message from the client before using send_message()?
Unfortunately, ignoring those errors leads to a permanent account ban.
I'd be very glad if anyone could help.
I tried:

using ChatMember.restricted_by (didn't work for no reason)
using Chat.is_restricted (didn't for user-based restrictions)

